# What facts are related to get faster video streaming on Android device?

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, android-videoview

I am developing an android app which plays a video from a server where I stored my video content. But it takes too much time to play a video, using 300-400 kb/s it takes almost 15-20 sec.
I want to know what facts are related to stream faster and how can I solve my problem.

Comment: mainly bandwidth

Comment: have a read here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27128904/converting-html5-video-what-software-to-use/27136611#27136611 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50671723/chrome-and-safari-html5-video-rendering-hanging-on-first-frame/50672639#50672639 - you'll want to optimize the video

Answer (score 0):

It could be:

- The video bitrate is too high for the connection speed
- The player initial buffering is too safe

If you're saying your network is 300-400kbps, you probably want to try converting your video to an adaptive format like HLS or DASH, where the player will detect the user's bandwidth and download the best quality version that can start quickly.

From there it could be player configuration, adjusting the amount of buffered video the player waits for before starting playback. But beware, reducing initial buffering can cause rebuffering later in playback.