# Android - ExoPlayer start playing as soon as possible without too much buffering

Tags: java, android, video, exoplayer

I am using a simple exoplayer test code to play videos from an URL and I noticed that after the player connects, it buffers about 2-3 seconds until it starts playing (I am referring to approximately 2-3 seconds because I do not know exactly how it works internally, it may be a certain number of bytes). Giving the fact that it takes about 1-2 seconds to connect (then to start buffering, then effectively start the video) it takes about 4 seconds to start the video, which seems like too much. I tested with a 3 seconds video, 640x480, 1.23MB in size, on a connection of detected speed ~24Mbits/s using a speed test app).

Is there a way to speed up the startup of the video (for example, by setting the initial buffering size needed to start)?

This is my testing code:

```
TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector();
player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);

PlayerView playerView = findViewById(R.id.player_view);
playerView.setPlayer(player);
DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,
            Util.getUserAgent(this, "simpleAudioApp"));
dataSourceFactory = new CacheDataSourceFactory(getSimpleCacheInstance(),
            dataSourceFactory);

Uri audioSourceUri = Uri.parse("http://...somevideo.mp4");
MediaSource audioSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
            .createMediaSource(audioSourceUri);
LoopingMediaSource loopingSource = new LoopingMediaSource(audioSource, 1);

// Prepare the player with the source.
player.prepare(loopingSource);
player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
player.addListener(new Player.EventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
            if (playbackState == Player.STATE_ENDED) {
                Toast.makeText(TestActivity2.this, "Video ended", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(TestActivity2.this, "video state chnged: " + playbackState, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRepeatModeChanged(int repeatMode) {
            Toast.makeText(TestActivity2.this, "repeat chnged: " + repeatMode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Is there any way of achieving this?

Comment: have a read here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27128904/converting-html5-video-what-software-to-use/27136611#27136611 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50671723/chrome-and-safari-html5-video-rendering-hanging-on-first-frame/50672639#50672639 - you'll want to optimize the video so it's got something to work with as quickly as possible

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use custom loadcontrol with this pattern:

```java
DefaultLoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl
.Builder()
.setBufferDurationsMs(minBufferMS, maxBufferMs, bufferForPlayackMS, bufferForPlaybackAfterRebufferMs)
.createDefaultLoadControl();
```

Sample usage:

```java
TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector();
    
DefaultLoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl
.Builder()
.setBufferDurationsMs(32*1024, 64*1024, 1024, 1024)
.createDefaultLoadControl();
player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector, loadControl);
```

Comment: In latest `exoplayer 2.11.8` version, how to pass this load control.

Comment: player =  new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(context, renderersFactory)
                .setTrackSelector(trackSelector)
                .setLoadControl(loadControl)
                .build();

Comment: 1. loadControl = DefaultLoadControl(
            DefaultAllocator(true, 1024),
            1000, // this is it!
            2000,
            1500,
            3000,
            1024,
            true
        )
2.
        simpleExoPlayer = SimpleExoPlayer
            .Builder(context)
            .setLoadControl(loadControl)
            .build()

Comment: in latest exoplayer, DefaultTrackSelector() deprecated and you need to pas context in it DefaultTrackSelector(context)

Comment: it still buffering after video playing , is it not possible that it buffer fully at a time then play it?

Comment: @AsukNath Would it be possible to have a quick chat about your NAGIOS API project from Github? I'm know this comment is offtopic...